# How to return values only after useEffect completes its execution in custom hook react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, frontend

I have a custom hook, where based on the length of data and connector, it's set the layout of grid. But initially, its sending as empty values for which the layout is broken initially and getting displayed correctly in few seconds.

While debugguing, the custom hook itself is returning empty value and once useEffect completes execution and sets the internal state in hook, its returning the layout class.

I have added the hook in stackblitz, and can see the empty values getting returned from hook in console.

Can anyone help me fix this empty values returning from the hook. Thanks in advance

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hsxkei?file=src/App.js

Comment: You're fixing the wrong thing. Instead the question you should be asking is what should you render instead of the layout while the layout is broken. If you are OK about rendering a white empty page then render that (have React render `null` or an empty string to simulate the browser not rendering anything). But this is an opportunity, not a problem. Instead of the old browser behavior of displaying white screen while waiting you have the opportunity to render something! For example a spinner or a loading screen or like Facebook fake content animation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect can't be called before first render, so it's impossible to calculate things before first render.

In your case you have few options:

1. Handle case with empty values (prevent your layout from being broken)
2. Use something like react-skeleton to show user at least some UI while correct UI is being calculated, use will guess that everything is loading and he should wait a little.
3. Move your calculation to some function, and run it on initialization and in your useEffect. For example you move all your code from useEffect to calculate function and check whether your UI is initialized, if not, you run that func

The third option would look similar to this

```
const calculateLayout = () => {
    const getLayoutFn = hasKeylineDivider
      ? setLayoutWithDivider
      : setLayoutWithoutDivider;

    const { fontSize, grid, padding } = getLayoutFn(
      incentiveData.length,
      partitionIndex
    );

    setCustomFontSize(fontSize);
    setGridWrapperArea(grid);
    setCustomValuePadding(padding);
}

if(!isInitialized) {
    calculateLayout();
    setIsInitialized(true)
}

useEffect(() => {
   calculateLayout()    
}, [hasKeylineDivider, incentiveData.length, partitionIndex]);
```